# Is the expression "Come what may" an exclamative?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion, exclamations

A bit of a split-hair question, but should the word "come" in "come what may" be understood as an imperative, and therefore "come what may" is an exclamative (as in "Come! Whatever may come/may happen, come!)?

Or is it just an inversion of "what(ever) may come"? If this is the case, shouldn't "may" be the inverted word and not "come"?

Thanks all!

Comment: It's a fixed expression...possibly subjunctive in origin